# PMD rule to find annotations in java

Tags: java, annotations, pmd

Does anyone know if PMD has the capabilities to find annotations? E.g. If I have a `@BeforeClass` annotation in my JUnit testclasses, will xpath treat the annotation as being just another node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can see example of rules interfering with annotations [here](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/java/migrating.html#JUnit4TestShouldUseBeforeAnnotation). Also look at the next few to follow. All of them deal with annotation checks.

Comment: That's excellent.Thanks for that. I found the PMD rule desgner in Eclipse really useful as well.